# How to Php (windowns 7) connect PostgreSQL in linux

Tags: php

I want to connect to PostgreSQL in linux with php in windows.

Fatal error:Call to undefined function pg_connect()

Thank you.

Comment: Can you make your question a little clearer please? We need info of your setup and code etc to be able to advise.

Comment: You already said that, with the addition of "in windows". Again, your question is unclear. All you are saying is "I want to do something". What do you mean by "connect to PostgreSQL in Linux with PHP in Windows"?  What code do you have? What does not work? What do you want to happen? What have you tried?

Comment: PostgreSQL in linux with php in windows :o  , can you expalin this and please add some code

Comment: Mr.James,  I mean by "connect to PostgreSQL in Linux with PHP in Windows" 
and my code 
<?php 
//Connection,
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=XXXXXXX port=5432 dbname=test user=tests password=tests")
or die ('Could not connect: '.pg_last_error());


?>    

Error Message:Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in C:\AppServ\www\test.php

I never set up on linux.

Comment: function `pg_connect()` does not exist. There is your starting point, then. Function code or file not included?

Answer (score 0):

PDO would be prefer to connet database. 
For this you need to enable PDO for **pg_sql**. Please alter **php.ini** file for pg_sql.

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "postsgres";
$username = "postgres";
$password = "postgres";
try{
    $dbh = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$database;host=$hostname",$username,$password);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I already tried this ways but it not work.
Should what I set config ?
Detail:
 I installed appserv-win32-2.6.0

Comment: @Siwan, this new info should have been in your question originally, as now rut2 has tried to help you with their answer, but having to guess what you want due to a lack of information from you they have wasted their time. You need to add some details to your question. As it stands, it's extremely unclear what you are asking, and we do not know what you've tried. We are willing to help, but you have to put some work in yourself and make a decent question which we can actually answer.